# Como lograr cambiar el background de un row sin perder su forma, android studio

Tags: java, android, studio, cardview

estoy intentando cambiar el background, lo consigo, pero cuando le pongo color, se pierde la forma

```
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

            View row1 = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
            TextView tv1=row1.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            TextView tv2=row1.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
            TextView tv3=row1.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
            TextView tv4=row1.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
            tv1.setText(ttl[position]);
            tv2.setText(dsc[position]);
            tv3.setText(dni[position]);
            tv4.setText(tipo[position]);
            if(tv4.getText().toString().equals("Enviaste")){                row1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
            } else if(tv4.getText().toString().equals("Pagaste")){                row1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light));
            } else if(tv4.getText().toString().equals("Cobraste")){
                row1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
            } else {
                row1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
            }
            return row1;
        }
```

[image: Asi queda]

ahora, si quito la programacion, queda asi:

[image: sin programacion]

Tambien intente hacercon con cardview, pero no hay forma, no consigo cambiar el color de fondo

Drawable Shape Corner Radius:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>

<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#ff000000"
    />

<padding android:left="1dp"
    android:top="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:bottom="1dp"
    />

<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>
```

Comment: Hola, Cual forma se pierde?

Comment: Hola! se pierde la forma de Corner radius, en la primera imagen se ve, se colorea todo el cuadro row, ahora, si no coloreo programaticamente, ahi si se visualizar el corner radius del row, que es la segunda imagen

Comment: Agrega por favor el drawable o shape que aplicas a tus celdas

Comment: listo ahi lo subi al post

Comment: Intenta crear dos shapes, uno en rojo y otro en verde, y no setees el background como color sino como drawable usando el shape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final me fui por crear un Cardview, y ahi pude darle forma y color

```
View row = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);

        TextView tv1=row.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        ImageView cobraste = row.findViewById(R.id.cobraste);
        ImageView recibiste = row.findViewById(R.id.recibiste);

        CardView carditem1 = row.findViewById(R.id.carditem1);

        tv1.setText(ttl[position]);
        tv2.setText(dsc[position]);

        if(tv4.getText().toString().equals("Cobraste")){
            carditem1.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_100));
            cobraste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_100));

        } else if(tv4.getText().toString().equals("Recibiste")){
            carditem1.setCardBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green_200));
            recibiste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]